# How to extract freehand writing from submitted PDF form?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I need to extract freehand writing from submitted PDF form or submit the writing as Base64 string (the form would submitted as XML in that case). i wold need to access the writing using PDF JavaScript, serialize it and submit it along other field values. how do I access the writing sing in-PDF JavaScript (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html)? Thanks

Comment: How was the handwriting entered?

Comment: Using "pencil tool" of Adobe Reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit the handwriting created by the pencil tool as XML (XFDF format) to your server by setting the submit button to submit field data and comments. There's no need to use JavaScript if the user will just be pressing the button.

[image]

If you do need to access the functionality through a script, you can achieve the same thing by using this.submitForm() and setting the bAnnotations parameter to true. See link for further documentation.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FDoc_methods.htm%23TOC_submitFormbc-106&rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_105

The "ink" annotations will be stored in the XML as a series of vertices that represent the strokes of the pencil tool. These can be imported into another PDF or rendered to an image for OCR... the Google Vision API does a pretty nice job of interpreting handwriting.